# Issue with Google Map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, proxy-server

I'm using a proxy server to connect to internet..
My emulator's browser is connecting to internet,but the maps app is not connecting and the google map app which i wrote is showing only the grid.I used google api key in main.xml and added INTERNET.PERMISSION in manifest.xml.
When i searched the issue in google..,i found out that the google map app doesn't work if we use proxy server.

**Is it True?..Is there any solution to it? Plz help me...**

### manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.googlemap"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity android:name=".GoogleMapActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"        
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> 

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  </application>

  </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

inside `<application></application>` tags?

Comment: Keep <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> outside <application> tag

Comment: I corrected my code as you said but Map is not loading ..only grids are visible

Answer (score 0):

In Proxy it will not work. You must have to work with map without proxy setting.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have created keystore and proper Map API key, if this is not then create your own keystore and appropriate map key using the below steps:

1. step 1: find the AVD's debug.keystore (windows--> perferences --> android --> build "default debug keystore") . Then rename this file. (maybe debug11.keystore)
2. step2: use cmd tool and get into C:\Documents and Setting \XXXXuser.android execute the command: `keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.key store -alias androiddebugkey -keyalg RSA -validity 10000`
3. step3: then execute the command get MD5 fingerprint keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore
4. step4: use this MD5 fingerprint get apikey from http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html
5. step5: use the map api key.